# If $X$, $Y$ are independent random variables and $E[X+Y]$ exists, then $E[X]$ and $E[Y]$ exist.

Tags: probability, expectation

I've been trying to show E$|X+Y|$ < $\infty$ $\Rightarrow$ E$|X|$ < $\infty$ by showing E$|X|$ $\leq$ E$|X+Y|$, but I'm stuck and cannot proceed from here.

Someone can help me, please?

-----[added]-----

$$E|X+Y| = \int\int|x+y|f_X f_Y\mathsf dx\mathsf dy = \int E|X+y|f_Y\mathsf dy < \infty.$$

So, can I say that $E|X+y| < \infty$ for almost every $y$ including $y=0$?

Comment: Your inequality $E|X| \leq E|X+Y|$ need not be true. Take for instance $X=2$, and $Y=-2$. These random variables (which happen to be deterministic) are independent, but $E|X|=2$, and $E|X+Y|=0$. If you want to have a truly stochastic example, you can let $X$ have a narrow distribution around $2$, and likewise let $Y$ have a narrow distribution around $-2$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I realised that my first approach was wrong.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/470054/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/618674/321264

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your second approach works. If $X$ and $Y$ are independent and $|X+Y|$ is integrable, then
$$
E|X+Y| = \int|x+y|dP_{(X,Y)}(x,y)=\int\left[\int|x+y|dP_X(x)\right]dP_Y(y)
$$
by Fubini's theorem, and moreover the function $$y\mapsto\int|x+y|dP_X(x)=E|X+y|$$ is integrable with respect to $P_Y$, hence finite almost surely. Pick any  $y$ for which $E|X+y|$ is finite and use
$$
|X|=|X+y-y|\le|X+y|+|y|$$
to conclude that  $X$ is integrable.

Comment: +1. In other words, the only error of the OP was to "deduce" that |X+y| is integrable for y=0 instead of being integrable for almost every y hence for at least one y, which suffices to conclude.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer was very helpful to me. Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ and $Y$ independent random variables such that their cumulative distribution functions are $F$ and $G$. Then the CDF of their sum is $$H(t)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty F(t-x)\,dG(x) $$
If $X+Y$ is integrable then it's absolute integrable and $E|X+Y|\geq \int\limits_{0}^\infty 1-H(t)\,dt $. By using Fubini's theorem we get
$$\int\limits_{0}^\infty 1-H(t)\,dt= \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty\int\limits_{0}^\infty 1-F(t-x)\,dt\, dG(x)$$
where $$\int\limits_{0}^\infty 1-F(t-x)\,dt=\left[t(1-F(t-x))\right]_{t=0}^\infty-\int\limits_{0}^\infty t\,d[1-F(t-x)]=E(X\cdot I[X>-x]) +x$$ is finite for almost every $x$, thus $E(X^+)$ is finite. Similarly we can show, that $E(X^-)$ is finite, hence $EX=EX^+-EX^-$ is finite.

Comment: Thank you for the solution! But it seems like this solution is beyond my current capacity to understand... will there be any other solution using simpler methods and preferably more intuitive one? :)