# Independent $X$ and $Y$ with $\mathbb{E}[|X+Y|]$ being finite, prove $\mathbb{E}[|X|]$ is finite.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value

Let random variables $X$ and $Y$ be independent with $\mathbb{E}[|X+Y|]<\infty$
Prove that $\mathbb{E}[|X|]$ is finite.

I was trying hard to use the independence condition, but since some of some random variables can have expectations being infinite, I’m not sure how to correctly use this condition. Can anyone give a hint? Thanks!

Comment: Use a (commonly overlooked) implication of Fubini's theorem.

Comment: Also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1219633/321264.

Comment: Can I say that $\mathbb{E}[|X+Y|]=\int_{R}(\int_{R}|x+y|\mu[dx])\mu[dy]\ge \int_{R}(\int_{R}(|x|-|y|)\mu[dx])\mu[dy]= \int_{R}(\mathbb{E}[|X|]-|y|)\mu[dy]$,   assume the statement is wrong and use the fact that $\mathbb{E}[|X|]-|y|$ is infinite to prove the statement?