# Why independence matters in a question

Tags: probability

I need some clarification on this question. [If $X \perp Y$ and $X+Y \in L^1$ then $X,Y \in L^1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/470054/if-x-perp-y-and-xy-in-l1-then-x-y-in-l1)

Why is the independence between X and Y needed. Is there a proof that the statement won't hold if X and Y are dependent or are there some simple counterexamples to this?

EDIT:

Just to clarify, how would one show that if $X$ and $Y$ are dependent random variables and $X+Y$ is integrable, then it doesn't necessary imply that $X$ and $Y$ are integrable.

Comment: $d\Bbb{P}(Y \leq y) \neq d\Bbb{P}(Y \leq y|X\leq x)$ if they are not independent (in the second equality of the second para of the first proof)

Comment: I see. But that's for making that specific proof work. Why would independence be needed? Is there a counterexample or some proof that shows the statement doesn't hold for dependent random variables. I'll clarify the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being integrable is weaker than being in $L^1$. Being in $L^1$ implies the expectation of the absolute value is finite: $$X \in L^1 \leftrightarrow \Bbb{E}[|X|] = \int_{\Omega} |X| dP < \infty.$$

With this in mind, we can clearly let $X$ be any r.v. not in $L^1$, let $A$ be any r.v. in $L^1$, and define $Y := A - X$. Then $X + Y = A \in L^1$, but $X$ and $Y$ are not independent and $Y$ is not in $L^1$.

For concreteness, you could let $X$ have a [Cauchy distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution) and $A$ be [exponentially distributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution).